# Этимология слова "корточки"

Tags: этимология

И еще о наклонах и прочих приближениях к земле)))
Задумалась над словом "корточки". Какая у этого слова этимология?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово КОРТОЧКИ этимологически связано со словом КОРОТКИЙ. Праслав. *kortъkyi является полн. формой прил.* kоrtъкъ «короток», От слова **кортъки** происходит уменьш. *кортъчьки* > корточки «укороченные, согнутые» (ноги): сидеть на корточках, — на согнутых ногах (присев), держась на носках. От **корт-** «короткий» происходит и диал. *кортеть* «ждать, притаившись». (Этимологический словарь Цыганенко)

Comment: А корчиться оттуда же?

Answer (score 1):

Я слышал в передаче "Галилео", что слово "корточки" произошло от старославянского глагола "кортеть" (кого-то поджидать, подстерегать).